# TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined modal

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to display a modal with the information of a certain item. But when I call the function it reads:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined at Scope.$scope.openModal

I was hoping someone could tell me why, here is the relevant code:

**Template**

```
<div ng-controller="View1Ctrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title">Item Details</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <ul ng-repeat="i in items">
                <li>Type: <span ng-bind="i.type"></span></li>
                <li>Description: <span ng-bind="i.description"></span></li>
                <li>Date: <span ng-bind="i.createDate"></span></li>
                <li>Priority: <span ng-bind="i.priority"></span></li>
                <li>Finished: <span ng-bind="i.isDone"></span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$close()">OK</button>
        </div>
    </script>
</div>
```

**App.Js**

```
'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
angular.module('myApp', [
  //'ngRoute',
  'ui.router',
  'ui.bootstrap',
  'myApp.view1',
  'myApp.view2',
  'myApp.version',
  'myApp.items'
])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/view1');

    $stateProvider  
    .state('view1', {
        url: '/view1',
        templateUrl: 'view1/view1.html',
        controller: 'View1Ctrl'
    })
    .state('view2', {
        url: '/view2',
        templateUrl: 'view2/view2.html',
        controller: 'View2Ctrl'
    });       
});
```

**Controller**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.view1', ['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/view1', {
        templateUrl: 'view1/view1.html',
        controller: 'View1Ctrl'
    });
}])
.controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope','itemsService',function($scope,itemsService, $uiModal) {

    $scope.$on('itemSwitch.moreInfo', function(event, obj){
        $scope.openModal(obj);
    });

    $scope.openModal = function (obj) {

        var modalInstance = $uiModal.open({
            animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
            templateUrl: 'templates/modalTemplate.html',
            controller: 'View1Ctrl',
            resolve: {
                items: function () {
                    return obj;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}]); //END
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to fix this issue?

Thanks

---

The error is gone, but now it doesn't show anything but the grey-out screen, the console shows the modal html is loading but not displaying properly.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your injection signature is not correct. You are missing `$uiModal`. Observe the following...

```
.controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope', 'itemsService', 
    function($scope, itemsService, $uiModal) {
```

=>

```
.controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope', 'itemsService', '$uiModal', 
    function($scope, itemsService, $uiModal) {
```

I am not totally sure the exact name of the service you are intending to inject. I guess here based on your *variable* that is named `$uiModal`, however, I notice the [docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) state it is `$uibModal`. You'll need to verify this.

---

In response to your updated newly found issue, my best observation is that `templateUrl: ''` and `<script id="">` must **match**. Try changing your `<script>` tag to the following...

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="templates/modalTemplate.html">
    <!-- <div> -->
```

I stumbled upon this while playing around with the [default plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) found in the docs. If both values are not the same there is an error.

Comment: You are right, but the name had to be changed to uibModal, apparently they changed it. The downside is that when I click the button the modal doesn't show (no errors thou)

Comment: hehe just edited my question after I looked that up in the docs ;) Unsure why it might not be showing, at least your error is gone. I can look a bit further...

Comment: odd I am not sure by looking at what you have provided. Could you supply a plunker which reproduces the issue?

Comment: I gave my best shot at guessing what the issue is, but I'm kind of at a loss since the first issue was fixes. At least check out my edited suggestion? Hope it helps